# How to return mean value (or expectation value) of a distribution estimated via function KernelDensity of sklearn, in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, kernel-density

My question is, how to return the mean value and variance of the estimated "kde"? Or is there any other package you known that can easily output mean value or variance value, like `print kde.mean()` or `print kde.get_parameter(mean)`?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

N = 100
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N))))[:, np.newaxis]

X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(X)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you need to do this numerically. I suggest 2 different approaches:

- Integration
- Monte Carlo Simulation

These approaches work for any **kernel** and any **bandwidth**.

## Integration

Uses the fact that once we know the **probability density function**, we can easily compute mean and variance via integration.

[image: mean and variance]

Note that in `scikit-learn` the method `score_samples` returns log pdf and therefore one needs to "exp" it.

## Monte Carlo Simulation

The idea here is to simply sample from your KDE and estimate population mean and variance via sample mean and variance.

---

## Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

N = 100
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N))))[:, np.newaxis]

X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(X)

# Mean and Variance - Integration
pdf = lambda x : np.exp(kde.score_samples([[x]]))[0]
mean_integration = quad(lambda x: x * pdf(x), a=-np.inf, b=np.inf)[0]
variance_integration = quad(lambda x: (x ** 2) * pdf(x), a=-np.inf, b=np.inf)[0] - mean_integration ** 2

# Mean and Variance - Monte Carlo
n_samples = 10000000
samples = kde.sample(n_samples)

mean_mc = samples.mean()
variance_mc = samples.var()


print('Mean:\nIntegration: {}\nMonte Carlo: {}\n'.format(mean_integration, mean_mc))
print('Variance\nIntegration: {}\nMonte Carlo: {}\n'.format(variance_integration, variance_mc))
```

Output:

> Mean:
>   Integration: 3.560582852075697
>   Monte Carlo: 3.5595633705830934
>
> Variance:
>   Integration: 6.645066811078639
>   Monte Carlo: 6.646732489654485

Answer (score 0):

## Principle

I ran into the same situation and you can find a working implementation for expectation in the `statsmodels` library, however interestingly enough it is patching `scipy` and not doing the same functions in it's own library.

They seem to have `expect()`, `expect_v2()` and `expect_discrete()` which uses a similar technique in the other answer that uses `scipy.integrate.quad` to do numerical integration.

## TL;DR version

Also if you're lazy like me and go with the default sampling that `statsmodels` infers, you can get a quick expectation value by replacing the numerical integration with the dot product of `density` and `support`. It's probably 'close enough' for most purposes.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy

N = 100
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N))))[:, np.newaxis]

X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(X)
kde.fit(kernel='gau', bw=0.5)

mean1 = np.dot(kde.density, kde.support) / kde.density.sum()
mean2 = scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: kde.evaluate(x)  * x, kde.support[0], kde.support[-1])
print('TL;DR version - Mean:', mean1)
print('Integration version - Mean:', mean2)

print('TL;DR version - Variance:', np.dot(kde.density, kde.support**2) / kde.density.sum() - mean1**2)
print('Integration version - Variance:', scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: kde.evaluate(x)  * x**2, kde.support[0], kde.support[-1])[0] - mean2[0]**2)
```

Output:

```
TL;DR version - Mean:           3.5605148164179368
Integration version - Mean:    (3.5604536291684905, 1.9311947816995413e-08)
TL;DR version - Variance:       6.646077637181225
Integration version - Variance: 6.644042199345121
```

## Difference between quad and dot

Please note that the `quad` method will not work with kernels other than Gaussian due to lack of `evaluate()`. For example, if you pass `kernel='epa', fft=False` when you fit, the only way is to use `numpy.dot` currently. This might change in future versions.

As an interesting effect, the seaborn library relies on `statsmodels` to display it's kde's however only works with Gaussian due to the above reason. For cdf's, it will show you the Gaussian cdf even if a different one is specified; pdf's seem to still honor the kerenel specification.

## Reference

[statsmodels.sandbox.sppatch](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/sandbox/distributions/sppatch.py)

Also reproduced here in case the repository changes [Latest commit bfa3e69 on Jan 22], however if using this algorithm with `statsmodels` you might have to replace the `pdf` calls with `evaluate` calls.